# How to convert textbox to float only if not empty?

Tags: c#

How can I convert a textbox into a float only when the textbox has value?

I currently have this `float test = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textbox.Text);`

It works fine, But gives an error if the textbox is empty.

Comment: Check for textbox not empty before you try convert to float.

Comment: take a look at tryparse().  (msdn  pagealready includes examples)

Comment: your question answers itself - "if the textbox is empty" - convert that to code and you'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think that better solution will be:

```
float test = float.NaN;
if(float.TryParse(textbox.Text, out test ))
{
     // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but generally you test with an `if`. For example:

```
float test;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.text))
    test = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textbox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very common way is to use [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the conversion. This way you can handle empty and invalid values with a single statement.

```
bool success = double.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value);
```

Don't forget to check `success` and handle a possible failure.

Answer (score 0):

It really is as simple as including this in an If statement.

```
float test;

if(textbox.Text.Length > 0) //Or (textbox.Text != "")
    test = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textbox.Text);
```

As an additional suggestion, multiple layers of validation is always a good thing. If you have something like a submit button, you should test against required fields being empty on the UI BEFORE it gets to the point where it is converted.